# $("<div/>").text(value).html is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am getting an `$("<div/>").text(value).html is not a function` error in the code below:

```
function htmlEncode(value) { 
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); 
}

function startImageUpload(imageuploadform, imagefilename){

    $('.imagef1_cancel').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).html(
        '<div>' + 
        htmlEncode(imagefilename) + 
        '<button type="button" class="imageCancel" cancel_image_file_name="' + 
        imagefilename + 
        '">CANCEL</button></div>'
    );

    return true;
}
```

How can this error be fixed?

Comment: what is '<div/>' in $('<div/>').text(value).html();

Comment: what exactly you are trying to return here `$('<div/>').text(value).html();`

Comment: It is just a div tag it is returning so that the value is displayed in its own div tag

Comment: I actually didn't get any error when running your code, but why not just concatenate the filename to the div like that: '<div>' + imageFileName + '</div>', why do you need special method for that?

Comment: @NaamaKatiee Because I need to get the name of the file and return it and it seems to do it with the html.encode. If you look at the second code I added then it works with a delete button, it just doesn't work with the cancel button

Comment: I'm running the code of the cancel button and get a nice "CANCEL" button ... would you like to provide your html code as well?

Comment: I have provided a link to my application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php). Here you will see the error in the app with no cancel button. Just upload a file. When file is uploaded you will see a delete button and a file name next to it, I want the similar thing to happen with cancel button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IM not sure wat you want but definitely the error is in this line

```
 return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
```

If you want to wrap that imagevalue in a div, simply use|

```
function htmlEncode(value) { 
    return '<div><img src="'+value+'"/></div>'; //wrapping  it as an image most probably you want this
}
```

Answer (score 4):

the output of

```
$('<div/>').text(value)
```

is a String and not a Jquery Object.

have you tried this

```
$($('<div/>').text(value)).html();
```

Comment: It only returns a string when you use `text()`. It returns a `jQuery` object when you supply a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The code works fine by itself:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/aae24/

You should check for anything strange in the string that you send into the function, that might mess up the code that is created. I have tried some different values though, and you can easily break the resulting markup (as you only html encode the value in one place, not the other), but the `htmlEncode` function still seems to run without an error message whatever you throw at it.

You can also check that the `$.html` property actually still is a function, so that you haven't accidentally changed it somewhere. The string value returns the function code:

```
alert($().html);
```