# $(...).text(...).html is not a function error recieved, how to fix it

Tags: jquery, html

I have a piece of code which by determining on wether an upload is successsful, cancelled or unsuccessful it displays the relevant messages:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){


      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
      }
      else if (success == 2){
          result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'"> The file upload was cancelled</span>';
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">There was an error during file upload</span>';
      }


    });
```

Now depending on the outcome of the upload I am trying to determine when each message should appear:

Current code of the iframe load:

```
$(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
                  $('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow;
                  stopImageUpload(2);

      $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").on("load",function() {
      stopImageUpload(1);
    }).attr("src", "cancelimage.php");
```

Original code of the iframe load:

```
$(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
                  $('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow;

      $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").on("load",function() {
      stopImageUpload(2);
    }).attr("src", "cancelimage.php");
```

What happended with the orignal code was that when a file uploaded succesfully, what happended was that a split second it displayed the success == 1 message but then straight away it displayed the cancel message which is success -- 2.

This was obviously incorrect so to try to fix it, I tried the current code solution so that what I thought would happen is that if cancelled, display the success == 2 message, if file was successful, it displays the success == 1 message and that message did not change.

The problem though is that the current code is providing a error below on this line while the orignal code never provided this error:

```
function htmlEncode(value) { return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); }
```

The error displaying is:

> typeError: $(...).text(...).html is not a function

My question is how can this error be fixed? I am assuming I need to change code in iframe load to prevent this.

**UPDATE:**

HTML:

```
<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_image' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' > 
    <p class='imagef1_upload_form' align='center'><label>
    Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/>
    <input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>
    <input type='reset' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel' value='Cancel' /></label>" +
    </p><p class='listImage' align='left'></p>" +
    <iframe class='upload_target_image' name='upload_target_image' src='#' style='width:0px;height:0px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>
```

JQuery:

```
var sourceImageForm;

function htmlEncode(value) { return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); }

//Function for when file starts uploading

function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','hidden');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagemsg').css('visibility','hidden');
  sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;

          $(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
                  $('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow;
                  stopImageUpload(2);

      $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").on("load",function() {
      stopImageUpload(1);
    }).attr("src", "cancelimage.php");

}); 
      return true;
}

      var imagecounter = 0;

//Function for after upload has stopped

function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';
      imagecounter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
      }
      else if (success == 2){
          result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'"> The file upload was cancelled</span>';
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">There was an error during file upload</span>';
      }

      $(sourceImageForm).find(".fileImage").replaceWith("<input type='file' class='fileImage' name='fileImage' />");

  var _imagecounter = imagecounter;

$('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {
    var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)
        .done(function(data) {

        $(".imagemsg" + _imagecounter).html(data);
    });

    $(this).parent().remove();
});

      return true;   
}

//clickHandler function which handle the submit when upload button is click

  function imageClickHandler(imageuploadform){ 
  if(imageValidation(imageuploadform)){ 
      window.lastUploadImageIndex = $('.imageuploadform').index(imageuploadform); 
      return startImageUpload(imageuploadform); 
  } 
  return false;
}
```

PHP (uploads file server side):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


session_start();


if ($_FILES['fileImage']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
$result = 0;


if (getimagesize($_FILES['fileImage']['tmp_name'])) {
if ((($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/jpg")) && ($_FILES['fileImage']['size'] > 0)) {
if (is_file("ImageFiles/" . $_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
$parts = explode(".", $_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
$ext   = array_pop($parts);
$base  = implode(".", $parts);
$n     = 2;

while (is_file("ImageFiles/" . $base . "_" . $n . "." . $ext))
    $n++;
$_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base . "_" . $n . "." . $ext;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
$result = 1;


}

else {
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
$result = 1;
}

}

}
} else {
echo "Upload was not successful";
}

?> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php
echo $result;
?>, '<?php
echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];
?>');</script>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598794/div-textvalue-html-is-not-a-function-error

Comment: @lam3r4370 The thing is that I also have a video and audio upload which works a similar way so I doubt I can use img source to wrap it around the div for those uploads as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `stopImageUpload` is missing an argument. It's signature is this:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){
```

but you call it like this:

```
stopImageUpload(1);
```

That means that you call `htmlEncode(undefined)` which leads to `$('<div>').text(undefined).html()`

jQuery supports two function signatures for the `text()` function. When passed a string, it sets the content and then returns the jquery object for chaining, and when passed nothing (undefined), it returns a string. In this case since you are passing `undefined` it returns a string, and then you try to call `html()` on a string, which does not exist.

#### Update

Okay, so based on the code you posted, you should never be calling `stopImageUpload` with `1` ever. That is handled by the image-uploading PHP logic. As you have it now, you are calling it in the `load` callback of the iframe on cancel, which isn't right. That means when you click `Cancel`, it will cancel the upload by changing the iframe source to a `cancelimage.php`, and when that PHP runs, it will say the upload succeeded, which it did not. I actually think you can just remove that `load` callback entirely from the click handler.

#### Update 2

I think your problem is related to multiple presses of 'cancel'. Try this:

```
var iframe = $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']");
iframe.on("load",function onLoad() {
    iframe.off("load", onLoad);
    stopImageUpload(2);
}).attr("src", "cancelimage.php");
```

Previously, any time you pressed cancel, you added a listener for 'load', but you never remove it, so even if, later on, you try to upload an image and it succeeds, the old listener would set it back to canceled. This new code will remove the listener after it fires, making that less likely.

Comment: @user1930247 You need to pass the proper filename, I guess? You haven't given enough info for me to even guess where that would come from. You changed the code, so I guess go look at the old version and see what changed?

Comment: @user1930247 Where did the filename come from in the original code? Where was `stopImageUpload(1);` called from?

Comment: @user1930247 Updated. Yeah, I don't think you should be calling that yourself. You aren't supposed to get success, right? That code you posted runs when you hit 'Cancel' so it's definitely not succeeding at uploading.

Comment: @user1930247 Updated again. Hope that works, I need to run for a bit.

Comment: @loganfsmyth `.text( undefined )` *does* return a jQuery object, and not a String, since version 1.7. OP must be using an older version of jQuery (1.6 or lower).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Im using jquery version 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

it is because $('').text(value) returns a string and not a jQuery object.So you cant append html() function since it doesnt exist.

```
return $("<div/>",{text:value}).html()
```

Comment: Nope. `text( value )` returns a jQuery object. When you don't pass the argument, i.e. `text()`, then you get a String.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas This is actually the root cause, though this answer doesn't give a proper fix since then code will still be broken. In the OPs code, `value` is undefined, so `text()` does in fact return a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what i understand, you want to insert msg into div as text, right?

so you can use this code:

```
var div = $('<div/>').text(value);
return div.html();
```

Comment: There is no difference between your code and the code in the question.

Comment: @NourBerro I tried your code, problem is that messes up the function as that it displays success message when cancelling upload. Also file uploaded will have its name undefined